# Sublassing NSImageRep to support new file format (pgm)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, pgm

Hi everyone! It is my first post here.

I am quite new in objective-c so maybe my question is not so hard but It is a problem for me. I've searched the web and didn't find any useful hints for me... I am writing a program in Objective-c in Xcode. I need to read and display a [pgm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) file (P5 with two bytes per pixel). To do that i'm trying to subclass `NSImageRep` but I don't know how to create a proper bitmap for this file and how to draw it. Below is my code so far:

header:

```
@interface CTPWTPGMImageRep : NSImageRep

@property (readonly)NSInteger width;
@property (readonly)NSInteger height;
@property (readonly)NSInteger maxValue;

+ (void)load;
+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredTypes;
+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredFileTypes;
+ (BOOL)canInitWithData:(NSData *)data;
+ (id)imageRepWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)file;
+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData*)pgmData;

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data;
- (BOOL)draw;

@end
```

and implementation:

```
#import "CTPWTPGMImageRep.h"

@implementation CTPWTPGMImageRep

@synthesize width;
@synthesize height;
@synthesize maxValue;

#pragma mark - class methods
+(void) load
{
    NSLog(@"Called 'load' method for CTPWTPGMImageRep");
    [NSImageRep registerImageRepClass:[CTPWTPGMImageRep class]];
}

+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredTypes
{    
    // This is a UTI
    NSLog(@"imageUnfilteredTypes called");
    static NSArray *types = nil;
    if (!types) {
        types = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"public.unix-executable", @"public.data", @"public.item", @"public.executable", nil];
    }

    return types;
}

+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredFileTypes
{
    // This is a filename suffix
    NSLog(@"imageUnfilteredFileTypes called");

    static NSArray *types = nil;
    if (!types)
        types = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pgm", @"PGM", nil];
    return types;
}

+ (BOOL)canInitWithData:(NSData *)data;
{
    // FIX IT
    NSLog(@"canInitWithData called");
    if ([data length] >= 2) // First two bytes for magic number magic number
    {
        NSString *magicNumber = @"P5";
        const unsigned char *mNum = (const unsigned char *)[magicNumber UTF8String];
        unsigned char aBuffer[2];
        [data getBytes:aBuffer length:2];
        if(memcmp(mNum, aBuffer, 2) == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"canInitWithData: YES");
            return YES;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"canInitWithData: NO");

    // end
    return NO;
}

+ (id)imageRepWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)file {
    NSLog(@"imageRepWithContentsOfFile called");
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
    if (data)
        return [CTPWTPGMImageRep imageRepWithData:data];
    return nil;
 }

+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData*)pgmData {
    NSLog(@"imageRepWithData called");
    return [[self alloc] initWithData:pgmData];
}


#pragma mark - instance methods

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data;
{
    NSLog(@"initWithData called");
    self = [super init];

    if (!self)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    if ([data length] >= 2) {
        NSString *magicNumberP5 = @"P5";
        const unsigned char *mnP5 = (const unsigned char *)[magicNumberP5 UTF8String];
        unsigned char headerBuffer[20];
        [data getBytes:headerBuffer length:2];

        if(memcmp(mnP5, headerBuffer, 2) == 0)
        {
            NSArray *pgmParameters = [self calculatePgmParameters:data beginingByte:3];
            width = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
            height = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
            maxValue = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

            if (width <= 0 || height <= 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Invalid image size: Both width and height must be > 0");
                return nil;
            }

            [self setPixelsWide:width];
            [self setPixelsHigh:height];
            [self setSize:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
            [self setColorSpaceName:NSDeviceWhiteColorSpace];
            [self setBitsPerSample:16];
            [self setAlpha:NO];
            [self setOpaque:NO];

            //What to do here?
            //CTPWTPGMImageRep *imageRep = 
              [NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:];

            //if (imageRep) {
            /* code to populate the pixel map */
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"It is not supported pgm file format.");
        }
    }
    return self;
  //return imageRep;
}

- (BOOL)draw
{
    NSLog(@"draw method1 called");
    return NO;
}
```

It is interesting that my `canInitWithData:` method is never called. Can you give me a hint how to smart read the Bitmap? I think that I need to use `initWithBitmapDataPlanes:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:bitsPerSample:samplesPerPixel:hasAlpha:isPlanar:colorSpaceName:bytesPerRow:bitsPerPixel:` but I don't know how to use it. How to create smart create (unsigned char **)planes from my `NSData` object? Do I need it?

May I use `NSDeviceWhiteColorSpace` which has white and alpha components (I don't need alpha)

```
[self setColorSpaceName:NSDeviceWhiteColorSpace];
```

and the most dificult part - I've completely no idea how to implement draw method. Any sugestions or hints?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

Ok. Now I have implementation according to NSGod directions:

```
@implementation CTPWTPGMImageRep

//@synthesize width;
//@synthesize height;

#pragma mark - class methods

+(void) load
{
    NSLog(@"Called 'load' method for CTPWTPGMImageRep");
    [NSBitmapImageRep registerImageRepClass:[CTPWTPGMImageRep class]];
}

+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredTypes
{
    // This is a UTI
    NSLog(@"imageUnfilteredTypes called");
    static NSArray *types = nil;
    if (!types) {
        types = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"public.unix-executable", @"public.data", @"public.item", @"public.executable", nil];
    }

    return types;
}

+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredFileTypes
{
    // This is a filename suffix
    NSLog(@"imageUnfilteredFileTypes called");

    static NSArray *types = nil;
    if (!types)
        types = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pgm", nil];
    return types;
}

+ (NSArray *)imageRepsWithData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"imageRepsWithData called");
    id imageRep = [[self class] imageRepWithData:data];
    return [NSArray arrayWithObject:imageRep];
}

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"initWithData called");
    CTPWTPGMImageRep *imageRep = [[self class] imageRepWithData:data];

    if (imageRep == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - instance methods

+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"imageRepWithData called");
    if (data.length < 2) return nil;
    NSString *magicNumberP5 = @"P5";
    const unsigned char *mnP5 = (const unsigned char *)[magicNumberP5 UTF8String];
    unsigned char headerBuffer[2];
    [data getBytes:headerBuffer length:2];

    if (memcmp(mnP5, headerBuffer, 2) != 0) {
        NSLog(@"It is not supported pgm file format.");
        return nil;
    }
    NSArray *pgmParameters = [self calculatePgmParameters:data beginingByte:3];

    NSInteger width = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];     // width in pixels
    NSInteger height = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];    // height in pixels

    NSUInteger imageLength = width * height * 2;                          // two bytes per pixel

    // imageData contains bytes of Bitmap only. Without header

    NSData *imageData = [data subdataWithRange:
                         NSMakeRange(data.length - imageLength, imageLength)];

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(imageData));
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGray); // kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                        height,
                                        16,
                                        16,
                                        width * 2,
                                        colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if (imageRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"CGImageCreate() failed!");
    }
    CTPWTPGMImageRep *imageRep = [[CTPWTPGMImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return imageRep;
}
```

as you can see I left the part with extending values between 0-255 because my pixels has values between 0-65535.

But It doesn't work. When I am choosing a pgm file from panel nothing happens. Bellow is my openPanel code:

```
- (IBAction)showOpenPanel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"showPanel method called");

    __block NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSImage imageFileTypes]];
    [panel beginSheetModalForWindow:[pgmImageView window] completionHandler:^ (NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSOKButton) {
            CTPWTPGMImageRep *pgmImage = [[CTPWTPGMImageRep alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[panel URL]]];

            // NSLog(@"Bits per pixel: %ld",[pgmImage bitsPerPixel]); // BUG HERE!

            NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] init];
            [image addRepresentation:pgmImage];
            [pgmImageView setImage:image];
        }
        panel = nil; // prevent strong ref cycle
    }];
}
```

Moreover, when i uncomment line with code `// NSLog(@"Bits per pixel: %ld",[pgmImage bitsPerPixel]); // BUG HERE!` just for check my Xcode freezes for a moment and I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in:

```
AppKit`__75-[NSBitmapImageRep _withoutChangingBackingPerformBlockUsingBackingCGImage:]_block_invoke_0:
0x7fff8b4823e8:  pushq  %rbp
0x7fff8b4823e9:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x7fff8b4823ec:  pushq  %r15
0x7fff8b4823ee:  pushq  %r14
0x7fff8b4823f0:  pushq  %r13
0x7fff8b4823f2:  pushq  %r12
0x7fff8b4823f4:  pushq  %rbx
0x7fff8b4823f5:  subq   $312, %rsp
0x7fff8b4823fc:  movq   %rsi, %rbx
0x7fff8b4823ff:  movq   %rdi, %r15
0x7fff8b482402:  movq   10625679(%rip), %rax
0x7fff8b482409:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x7fff8b48240c:  movq   %rax, -48(%rbp)
0x7fff8b482410:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x7fff8b482413:  callq  0x7fff8b383148            ; BIRBackingType  //EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, adress=...)
```

any help??? I have no idea what is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually much easier than you're thinking.

First of all, I would recommend making `CTPWTPGMImageRep` a subclass of `NSBitmapImageRep` rather than `NSImageRep`. That will take care of the "hardest" problem, since there will be no need to implement a custom `draw` method, as `NSBitmapImageRep`s already know how to draw themselves. (In OS X 10.5 and later, `NSBitmapImageRep` is basically a direct wrapper around CoreGraphics `CGImageRef`s).

I'm not that familiar with the PGM format, but what you'll basically be doing is creating a representation of the image in the closest destination format that matches the source format. To use a specific example, we'll take the [PGM example FEEP image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example) from Wikipedia.

```
P2
# Shows the word "FEEP" (example from Netpbm main page on PGM)
24 7
15
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  3  3  3  3  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0 15  0
0  3  3  3  0  0  0  7  7  7  0  0  0 11 11 11  0  0  0 15 15 15 15  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0  3  0  0  0  0  0  7  7  7  7  0  0 11 11 11 11  0  0 15  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

[image]

The closest native image to be able to portray the values in the example image would be a single channel grayscale image, 8 bits per pixel, no alpha. The plan then is to create a `CGImageRef` with the specified settings, and then use `NSBitmapImageRep`'s `initWithCGImage:` method to initialize the custom subclass.

I would first override the following two methods to both rely on the singular `+imageRepWithData:`:

```
+ (NSArray *)imageRepsWithData:(NSData *)data {
    id imageRep = [[self class] imageRepWithData:data];
    return [NSArray arrayWithObject:imageRep];
}

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data {
    CTPWTPGMImageRep *imageRep = [[self class] imageRepWithData:data];
    if (imageRep == nil) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }
    self = [imageRep retain];
    return self;
}
```

For me, it was necessary to implement the `+imageRepsWithData:` method to call the singular method before the image was able to be loaded properly.

I would then change the singular `+imageRepWithData:` method be as follows:

```
+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData *)data {
    if (data.length < 2) return nil;
    NSString *magicNumberP5 = @"P5";
    const unsigned char *mnP5 = (const unsigned char *)[magicNumberP5 UTF8String];
    unsigned char headerBuffer[20];
    [data getBytes:headerBuffer length:2];

    if (memcmp(mnP5, headerBuffer, 2) != 0) {
        NSLog(@"It is not supported pgm file format.");
        return nil;
    }
    NSArray *pgmParameters = [self calculatePgmParameters:data beginingByte:3];

    NSUInteger width = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    NSUInteger height = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
    NSUInteger maxValue = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

    NSUInteger imageLength = width * height * 1;

    NSData *imageData = [data subdataWithRange:
                        NSMakeRange(data.length - imageLength, imageLength)];
    const UInt8 *imageDataBytes = [imageData bytes];
    UInt8 *expandedImageDataBytes = malloc(imageLength);

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < imageLength; i++) {
        expandedImageDataBytes[i] = 255 * (imageDataBytes[i] / (CGFloat)maxValue);
    }

    NSData *expandedImageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:expandedImageDataBytes
                                               length:imageLength];
    free(expandedImageDataBytes);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(
                                          (CFDataRef)expandedImageData);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace =
             CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                        height,
                                        8,
                                        8,
                                        width * 1,
                                        colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    if (imageRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"CGImageCreate() failed!");
    }
    CTPWTPGMImageRep *imageRep = [[[CTPWTPGMImageRep alloc]
                                initWithCGImage:imageRef] autorelease];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return imageRep;
}
```

As you can see, we need to loop through the bytes in the original image and create a second copy of these bytes with the full expanded range between 0 and 255.

To make use of this image rep, you can call it like the following (being sure to use `NSImage`'s `initWithData:` method):

```
// if it hasn't been done already:
[NSImageRep registerImageRepClass:[CTPWTPGMImageRep class]];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feep" ofType:@"pgm"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
[self.imageView setImage:image];
```

One more note about your `+imageUnfilteredFileTypes` method: filename extensions are case insensitive, so there's no need to specify both lowercase and uppercase `@"PGM"`, you can just do lowercase:

```
+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredFileTypes {
    static NSArray *types = nil;
    if (!types) types = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pgm", nil];
    return types;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But unfortunately non of my 
+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredTypes;
+ (NSArray *)imageUnfilteredFileTypes;
+ (NSArray *)imageRepsWithData:(NSData *)data;
+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData *)data;
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data;
methods isn't even called when I'm trying to [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data]. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to simply read the pixel data into memory and just create an [`NSBitmapImageRep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from the pixel data instead of trying to create an image rep specifically for .pgm files.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your and NSGod idea.